# Recreate Chrome's "status text" functionality with WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, webbrowser-control, tooltip

I am trying to recreate Chrome's method of displaying the "status text" of the web page with a WebBrowser control.

These are two methods I am trying to recreate:

- Displays the text in a box in the bottom right (or left depending on cursor position) corner
- Displays URL of hyperlinks when hovered over

My method:

As of now I have thought of using a ToolTip control and displaying the text within that ToolTip using the WebBrowser.StatusTextChanged event.  Obviously this is a somewhat crude way to go about doing this.

So that leads me to two questions:

1: Using my current method, how could I set the position of the ToolTip to appear in the bottom-left corner of the WebBrowser control. (Note I'm using .NET 2.0)

2: What would be a more efficient way of doing this besides the method I've came up with so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use a Label and put it over your WebBrowser control, somewhere at the bottom. You'll have to take into consideration the webbrowser's horizontal scroll bar (there is a `WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled` property and then you can obtain the size of the scrollbar via `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` and positin the label so that it doesn't overlap the scrollbar).

I don't think that using ToolTips is a good idea because they have some limitations (they dissapear after a certain (system-defined) amount of time, they are always on top).

Comment: Using the ShowAlways property seemed to keep the ToolTip open, but using a standard Label is a lot easier to implement.  Thanks.